# A calculator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I made a calculator in JavaScript. Now, I want to rename my functions, variables, and input names. But I don't know how.

Here is my codes:

```js
function Calc() {
    var num1 = +txt1.value;
    var num2 = +txt2.value;
    var ch = +optxt.value;
    var result;
    if (ch == 1) {
        result = num1 + num2;
    }
    if (ch == 2) {
        result = num1 - num2;
    }
    if (ch == 3) {
        result = num1 * num2;
    }
    if (ch == 4) {
        result = num1 / num2;
    }
    if (ch == 5) {
        result = Math.pow(num1, num2);
    }
    if (ch == 6) {
        result = Math.pow(num1, 1 / num2);
    }
    p.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<script src="calculator-1.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="optxt" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
<br>
<button onclick="Calc()">Calculate</button>
<p id="p"></p>
```

Note: I **just** want to change names.

Comment: how does it work to access the DOM elements directly by there ids. Is this a special feature of Stackoverflow Code Snippets?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables#:~:text=The%20value%20of%20the%20name,accessible%20as%20a%20global%20variable. (it works, but it's bad practice)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the names of functions, variables, and input names without changing any other pieces of code, here are my suggestions.

- The `Calc` function could just be `Calculate`
- The `txt1` input could be `operand1`
- The `txt2` input could be `operand2`
- The `optxt` input could be `operator`
- The `ch` variable could be `operation`
- The `p` element could be `output` (either `id="output"` or change it to `<output></output>`)

But these are all just suggestions; it's completely up to you if you want these changes.

```js
function Calculate() {
  var num1 = +operand1.value;
  var num2 = +operand2.value;
  var operation = +operator.value;
  var result;
  if (operation == 1) {
    result = num1 + num2;
  }
  if (operation == 2) {
    result = num1 - num2;
  }
  if (operation == 3) {
    result = num1 * num2;
  }
  if (operation == 4) {
    result = num1 / num2;
  }
  if (operation == 5) {
    result = Math.pow(num1, num2);
  }
  if (operation == 6) {
    result = Math.pow(num1, 1 / num2);
  }
  output.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<script src="calculator-1.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="operand1" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="operator" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="operand2" />
<br>
<button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could name your input elements properly: `operand1` instead of `txt1` or at least `txtOperand1` if you like to prefix elements with their type.

If you really want to use numbers for the operators, at least use named constants: `const OP_ADD = 1;`, `const OP_SUBTRACT = 2;` and so on...

If you want to take advantage of the fact that Javascripts is a function language you could first map your input value for the operator to an `operation` function and the apply the input values to the function:

```
function getOperation(code) {
    switch (code) {
        case OP_ADD: 
            return (a, b) => a + b;
        case OP_SUBTRACT:
            return (a, b) => a - b;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Finally you can then apply the operation like this:

```
let operation = getOperation(optxt.value); 
let result = operation(txtOperand1.value, txtOperand2.value);
```

Comment: I don't want to change my code.

Comment: @Arian What do you mean you don't want to change your code?

Comment: Oops, pinged wrong person, you both start with A. @Arian The whole point of Code Review is to improve one's code, which can only be done by changing it

Comment: @CertainPerformance I **just** want to change names.